# document.activeElement not available on firefox addon's content script only for Gmail

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am developing a Firefox addon using the addon-sdk. This addon adds a menu item to the context menu and user can right click on any edit controls to activate this menu item. Once activated, it shows a small popup with suggestions when user types something.

Everything works well except on Gmail.

In Gmail, the below code fails.

```
self.port.on('showPopup', function(data) {
    var active = document.activeElement;
    console.log(active.type);
    if (active && getWordUnderCaret(active).word == data.input) {
        populateSuggestions(data);
        positionPopup(active);
        stylePopup();
    }
});
```

The reason for the failure is `document.activeElement` points to `document.body` and the `getWordUnderCaret` fails as it expects an input/textarea control. This works well in all other places. I am not sure why it points to `document.body` as I can see the focus is on the input control. Typing `document.activeElement` in Firebug console gives me proper object.

Alternatively, I tried to track the active element myself rather than using `document.activeElement`. But I ran into issues like persisting this somewhere. I can't use `window` to persist this as `window` is a proxy. I tried with `unsafeWindow` but couldn't get it to work.

I am wondering why this fails in Gmail? Any help to fix this would be great!

My code is available at [Github](https://github.com/navaneeth/varnam-browser-addons/blob/master/firefox/data/varnam.js#L38)

**Edit**

It looks like this is an issue with addon-sdk. I have created a Gist which can be used to reproduce the problem. It is available [here](https://gist.github.com/4544929)

Comment: By Gmail, do you mean the big box when you compose a new mail or the search box at the top?

Comment: Search box and textarea in chat windows

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I guess, you are referring to the big box on Gmail, where you enter the message-body when you compose an email.

» If that's the case;

### The Reason:

That edit control on Gmail is not a text control (input or textarea). That's a **[WYSIWYG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG)** editor implemented with an **`<iframe>`** which is made **editable** by setting `document.designMode = "on"` (or    `document.body.contentEditable = true` depending on the browser    support).

So, when clicked; you don't always get the right element with the way you query **`document.activeElement`**, in this case. You get the wrapping (main) document's `body`, (not even the `iframe`'s `body`).

For example; I believe, [at this line](https://github.com/navaneeth/varnam-browser-addons/blob/master/firefox/data/varnam.js#L25) of your code; you add a `click` event listener to the main document. But you should also add it to the **editable iframes** in the page; because the page and the iframe(s) have different `document` objects (and iframe will not set itself as active). So, you will get the wrong **`document.activeElement`**.

### Workaround:

Add the necessary event listeners to the iframes too; since you want to get notified about them.

```
// Add mouseup event listener to the main document
document.addEventListener('mouseup', logActiveElement, false);
// Get all the iframes on the main document.
var iframeElems = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
// Add mouseup event listener to the document of the iframe elements
for (var i = 0; i < iframeElems.length; ++i) {
    addIframeEvent(iframeElems[i], true, 'mouseup', logActiveElement);
}
```

Here are the helper functions:
*(Notice how we add event listeners to an iframe (document) from the main document and how we check whether or not the iframe is currently editable.)*

```
// Adds the specified event listener to the iframe element. 
function addIframeEvent(iframeElem, editableOnly, eventName, callback) {
    // Get the document of the iframe element.
    var iframeDocument = iframeElem.contentDocument || 
                            iframeElem.contentWindow.document;
    // Watch for editableOnly argument. 
    if ( (editableOnly && isDocEditable(iframeDocument)) || !editableOnly) {
        // Add the event listener to the document of the iframe element.
        iframeDocument.addEventListener(eventName, callback, false);
    }
}

// Checks whether the specified document is content-editable or in design mode.
function isDocEditable(doc) {
    return ( ('contentEditable' in doc.body) && (doc.body.contentEditable === true) ) || 
        ('designMode' in doc) && (doc.designMode == "on") );
}

// Handler function
function logActiveElement() {
    console.log("Active Element:", document.activeElement);
}
```

Now, the event handler will log the correct `activeElement` to the console.

### Complications:

As a result; things like text selections and inspections in your existing code, will not work the same way they do with regular edit controls (input, textarea, etc).

For example; your `getWordUnderCaret(editor)` function gets the `insertionPoint` by `editor.`**`selectionStart`** which does not exist in `document.body` (of the target `iframe`). For this kind of selection/inspection; you should switch between [**DOM Selections**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Selection), [**DOM Ranges**](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Traversal-Range/ranges.html); instead of text selection and ranges in [text edit control](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLTextAreaElement)s.

*Note: The text selection/range jQuery library ([Rangy](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/)) you use, promises to handle this kind of editable content within the browser (iframes, divs, etc). Have you tried that for iframes (on Gmail for example)?*

### Further Information:

- See **[activeElement documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.activeElement)** on Mozilla Developer
  Network. Aditinonally, it indicates: ***"Do not confuse focus with a
  selection over the document. When there is no selection, the
  `activeElement` is the page's `<body>`."***

### UPDATE:

To check the text controls on Gmail; I also played with your sample code;

- Added `attachTo: ["existing", "top", "frame"]` to PageMod options.
- Changed the value of `contentScriptWhen` to `'end'` (instead of
  `'ready'`) in PageMod options; to make sure everything including DOM, CSS, JS has been loaded. Some content may be altered via JS on page ready/load so 'end' will execute after it.
- Applied the selector context to the menu items too; in order to
  ensure the item only appears during the selector context.

Tested on Gmail (search box, chat box, etc) and other sites and; this seems to be working.
See/test the working [example **here** on addon builder](https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/package/171385/latest/).

[image: Gmail Search-box text input]

[image: Gmail Chat-box textarea]

Comment: Thank. But my issue was in the search box and textareas in chat windows.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using the latest git version of the addon sdk? The context menu there has been rewritten from scratch and I heard it fixes quite a few bugs.